# How to use Serial Port that was connected form another PC?

Tags: java, serial-port, hardware

There are 2 PC, the first PC is connect with a COM port (GSM Modem). How to send a SMS from the second PC via GSM Modem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two PC are connected by TCP/IP : send a message via socket from PC1/client to PC2/server then PC2/server sends SMS via COM Port to GSM.